# Struggling with Traceback Error and Operational Error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "read_data_two.py",
> line 59, in 
> insertIntoTable(info, count)     File "read_data_two.py", line 42 & 43, in insertIntoTable
> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO New_Packet VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (local_time, IP_Protocol, src_address, dest_address,
> transport_protocol)) sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Context: I am writing a code which will read from a file line by line. It will read each line from the text file. It will then split the line into a list, and each index of the list will contain a different attributes (in this case, the attributes will be info about packets (Transport Protocol, src_address, dest_address, IP protocol, and local time). I am having errors when I am trying to insert elements from a list. I have tried multiple ways, but when I input elements from a list, it literally gets read as a string. I tried the %s, but it is now causing error around the % sign. Also, I don't understand why I am getting an error when I am calling the insertIntoTable() function.

```
1) import sqlite3 #Gives program access to the sqlite3 module
2)
3)
4)def insertIntoTable(info, count):
5)  print(count)
6)  #print(type(info))
7)  local_time = info[0]
8)  #print(local_time)
9)  #print(type(local_time))
10) #print(info[0])
11)
12) IP_Protocol = info[1]
13) #print(type(IP_Protocol))
14) #print(info[1])
15)
16) src_address = info[2]
17) #print(info[2])
18)
19) dest_address = info[3]
20) #print(info[3x])
21)
22) transport_protocol = info[4]
23) #print(info[4])
24) #print(" ")
25)
26) connection = sqlite3.connect("PacketInfo.db")   #sqlite3.cnnect() function returns objects 27) #that will be used to interact with database 
28) cursor = connection.cursor()   #creates cursor object used to SQL statements to a SQLite 
29)
30)
31) #if count == 0:
32) if count == 0:
33)     cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS New_Packet (local_time VARCHAR , IP_Protocol 34)  VARCHAR, src_address VARCHAR, dest_address VARCHAR, transport_protocol VARCHAR)")
35) connection.commit()
36)     count += 1
37)     #count += 1
38)
39) #print(count)
40) #cursor.execute(f "INSERT INTO table VALUES {local_time}, {IP_Protocol}, {src_address}, 
41){dest_address}, {transport_protocol},")
42) cursor.execute("INSERT INTO New_Packet VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (local_time, 
43)  IP_Protocol, src_address, dest_address, transport_protocol))
44) connection.commit()


45) rows = cursor.execute("SELECT* FROM New_Packet").fetchall()   #fetchall() retrieves all the 
46) connection.commit()
47) #print("Made it")
48) print(rows)

49) cursor.close()
50) return

51)file = open("packets.txt","r")
52)list_of_info = []
53)count = 0

54)for line in file.readlines():  
55)        if not line:
56)         break
57)        info = line.split()
58)        print(info)
59)        insertIntoTable(info, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder for variable substitution for sqlite is `?` not `%s`. For example your insert statment should be:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO New_Packet VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (local_time, IP_Protocol, src_address, dest_address, transport_protocol))
```